# Payal Checkout. Change receiver's name

Tags: paypal, checkout

Instead of toaster@gmail.com (receiver's email) I need company name.

My code:

```
<form id="paymentform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paymentform" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="My Dev Site">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="toaster@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://toaster22.com/checkout/notify">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://toaster22.com/checkout/success">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://toaster22.com/checkout/cancel">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #427E-85FF-028E-E351">
        <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="427E-85FF-028E-E351">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="23.47">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">
</form>
```

What option can I use for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to display the company name to the buyer in the PayPal flow, you simply use a receiver account that is registered as a Business account. You still identify the receiver by email in your button; nothing needs to change in the button.

PayPal will display the email address for an unregistered seller, the accountholder's name for a personal/premier account, and the business name for a business account.